# Quadrants in slides using LyX and beamer

Tags: beamer, lyx, presentations, columns, lyx-layouts

In LyX to do columns on a `beamer` slide you have to do many sub tasks:

1. Columns (top aligned)
2. Column
3. Width
4. Indentation, for each paragraph in column
5. repeat 2--4 for second column

Is there maybe a more usable way to achieve this?

Nice would be to simply structure a slide into four quadrants – any idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `minipages` I defined a command with four arguments to divide a frame in four quadrants; each argument will hold the contents of each quadrant; feel free to adapt my example according to your needs (depending on the theme used is possible that a manual adjustment of the `minipage`s widths and or heights will be necessary):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand\FourQuad[4]{%
    \begin{minipage}[b][.35\textheight][t]{.47\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[b][.35\textheight][t]{.47\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}\\[0.5em]
    \begin{minipage}[b][.35\textheight][t]{.47\textwidth}#3\end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][.35\textheight][t]{.47\textwidth}#4\end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame divided in four quadrants}
\FourQuad%
{First quadrant contents and some more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text}%
{\vfill
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{2cm}
  \captionof{figure}{A test figure.}
  \label{fig:test}
}%
{\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
  &= c \\
  & = d.
\end{align*}}%
{Fourth quadrant contents and some more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

My example also shows how to use `\captionof` from the `caption` package to add captions to objects.

I, however, don't know how to implement my idea in LyX.

Here's the result of the example code:
[image]

Comment: Four minipages seem to do well enough, cheers! In Lyx they're more generally called Boxes

http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/FiguresSideBySide